# How to validate token from Localstorage and return currentUser from Apollo Server to React front-end?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, graphql, apollo

I already have a jwt middleware which verifies token and returns currentUser to React front-end:

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if(token !== "null") {
        try{
            const currentUser = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
        } catch {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
next();
});
```

Now, I want to integrate the logic into the following Apollo server:

```
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql(typeDefs),
  resolvers,
  context: async () =>({ 
  db,
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  }),
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

At the end, the value of currentUser should be available to be used at react front-end. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `currentUser` to the `request` object inside the middleware. Next, you pass it copy it from the request to the GraphQL context. Then you can add a `currentUser` resolver and simply return the user from the context.

Your middlware

```js
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if(token !== "null") {
        try{
            req.currentUser = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
        } catch {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
next();
});
```

Your server

```js
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: gql(typeDefs),
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) =>({ 
    currentUser: req.currentUser,
    db,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  }),
});

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

and the resolvers

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    currentUser: (parent, args, context) => context.currentUser,
    ...
  }
}
```

Add the corresponding type definition and you should be able to query the current user from your client.

If you need more information [here is a detailed tutorial](https://jkettmann.com/how-to-authenticate-using-graphql-and-jwt/) which might be of help.